Try to connect to database
the error
I am new in this field, so I want to connect to database and there are errors in files-no-error-detected, but if you open the files then the error will be detected. I haven't open the file that have error in it since I started make it. this is the error and I am really confused now because the error is not in the files that i'm working on right now. How to fix this? Thank You
This error too
I tried to connect and read data from database using Models and this is the error, and I don't really know why.

In your model you don't need the __construct function it will connect to your default database automatically. I'm not sure about your first error I'm afraid.
